# Java queuing mechanism

Tags: java, redis, message-queue, jedis

I am importing a large amount of data from files to a Redis database. So I have two steps to perform: parsing the files, then importing them using jedis.

I want to parse and import at the same times using one thread for each task to speed up the process.

What would be a good approach to exchange the data between those two threads? I suppose I need some kind of lightweight Java message queue.

Would Java Message Service be a good solution? Or could I just use a concurrent Java List?

Comment: Have you looked at [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)? I wouldn't bother with a messaging service if you're working with threads and not separate processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DaoWen said, since you are using threads you don't have to bother with an MQ. BlockingQueue and ConcurrentLinkedQueue should be fine.